# How can I make all elements equally wide in flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make all elements in one row of flexbox equally wide and would like to see the correct way used in my code.
.

Elements that are supposed to be same width have classes: "klawiatura_przycisk" and "klawiatura_przycisk_null".

```css
:root,html{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: #010440;
    font-family:arial;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #010440;
}
#main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #050259;
    float: left;
    color: whitesmoke;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #010440;
    color: #15038C;
}
footer > p{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
}
h1{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    display: table;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
header > h1:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left:0px;
}
li{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
}
li:hover{
    background-color: #050259;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input{
    background-color: #050259;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #15038C;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
select{
    background-color: #050259;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #15038C;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Projekt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="AplikacjeInternetowe_Projekt_Style.css">
    <style>
        .klawiatura_rzad{
            color: whitesmoke;
            margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
            align-self: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            flex-grow: 1;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            min-height: 60px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .klawiatura_przycisk{
            color: whitesmoke;
            background-color: #15038C;
            border: #15038C;
            margin: auto 5px auto 5px;
            align-self: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            flex-basis: auto;
            flex-grow: 1;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            min-height: 60px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .klawiatura_przycisk_null{
            margin: auto 5px auto 5px;
            align-self: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            flex-basis: auto;
            flex-grow: 1;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            min-height: 60px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .klawiatura_przycisk > span{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 onclick="window.location.href='AplikacjeInternetowe_Projekt_Index.html';">Aplikacje Internetowe <font color=#3805F2>Projekt</font></h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="window.location.href='AplikacjeInternetowe_Projekt_Modyfikacja.html';">Modyfikacja</li>
            <li onclick="window.location.href='AplikacjeInternetowe_Projekt_Kalkulator.html';">Kalkulator</li>
            <li onclick="window.location.href='';">3</li>
            <li onclick="window.location.href='';">4</li>
            <li onclick="window.location.href='';">5</li>
            <li onclick="window.location.href='';">6</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="main">
        <div style="background-color: #010440; margin: auto; align-self: center; align-content: center; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 113px; max-width: 500px; padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px; border-radius: 25px;">
            <div id="kalkulator_wyswietlacz" style="background-color: #15038C; color: whitesmoke; margin: auto; align-self: center; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: right; align-items: right; text-align: right; box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 50px; max-width: 400px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 25px; min-height: 60px; height: 5%;">
                <div id="kalkulator_linia_1" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                <div id="kalkulator_linia_2" style="width: 100%;">|</div>
            </div>
            <div id="kalkulator_klawiatura" style="border: #050259 solid 2px; color: whitesmoke; margin: auto; align-self: center; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; align-items: center; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 90px; max-width: 400px; padding: 10px; margin-top: 2%; border-radius: 25px; height: auto;">
                <div id="kalkulator_klawiatura_rzad1" class="klawiatura_rzad">
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        +
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="kalkulator_klawiatura_rzad2" class="klawiatura_rzad">
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        4
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        5
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        6
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        -
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="kalkulator_klawiatura_rzad3" class="klawiatura_rzad">
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        7
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        8
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        9
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        *
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="kalkulator_klawiatura_rzad4" class="klawiatura_rzad">
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk_null"></div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        0
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk_null"></div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        /
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="kalkulator_klawiatura_rzad5" class="klawiatura_rzad">
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        <span>&#8730;</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        x<sup>2</sup>
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        !
                    </div>
                    <div class="klawiatura_przycisk">
                        =
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>Autor:</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider using `display: grid` instead, as that lets you define `grid-auto-columns: 1fr` and all elements will have the same width to fill the container.

Comment: just use `flex: 1 ` or `flex-grow: 1` in children that should be equal in size.

Comment: Grid would be a much better option here because it is so much easier to work with. Using grid you can manage the column width, and gutter width all from the parent container. The only drawback is that you do not have the ability to reverse the columns (or rows) like flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`flex-basis: 100%;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-basis.asp) on the elements which you need to have equal width. A common class on each would help too. But with your current code you can do this:

```
[class*="klawiatura_przycisk"] { flex-basis: 100%; }
```

This CSS selector is called an ["attribute selector"](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) and it also uses a wildcard. It selects all elements with a "class" attribute containing the specified string.

Here is a real world example:

```css
.flex-row {
  padding: 10px;
  background: slategray;
  /* flex container */
  display: flex;
}

.flex-col {
  padding: 30px;
  background: cyan;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  /* columns get flex basis 100% */
  flex-basis: 100%;
}


/* nth-child selector for even numbered child elements */

.flex-col:nth-child(even) {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">column</div>
  <div class="flex-col">column</div>
  <div class="flex-col">column</div>
  <div class="flex-col">column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funny how you try to give a detailed answer then some know-it-all comes in and erases half the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  .klawiatura_przycisk .klawiatura_przycisk_null{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: space-evenly;
    
    }
```